# Pyjnius: Python crashes when accessing static variable from instance

Tags: static, crash, pyjnius

I have started to use Pyjnius and I am stuck with a serious bug.
I have not found any reference to it but it's so simple to obtain it, that I seriously doubt I am the first one to experience it.

Basically, if I try to access a static member of a class THROUGH AN INSTANCE, I get a crash of the whole Python interpreter, unless I have previously assigned a value to the member through the class.

My JAVA class is like that:

```
class TestClass {
    public static int b;
    public double c;

    public TestClass(int cc)  {
        c = cc;
    }
}
```

and my test Python script is simply:

```
from jnius import autoclass

the_class = autoclass('TestClass')

the_object = the_class(42.0)    # create an instance
print(the_object.c)             # no problem accessing the non-static member

the_object.c = 12.56
print(the_object.c)             # no problem modifying the non-static member

print(the_class.b)              # no problem accessing the static member from the class

#print(the_object.b)            # crash if I access the static member from the instance!!!!

the_class.b = 42
print(the_class.b)              # no problem modifying the static member from the class

print(the_object.b)             # and now I can also access it from the instance, but only after I have modified it
```

Now, if I uncomment the line where I access the_object.b BEFORE I have modified its value from the class, I get a complete crash of the Python interpreter.

The same crash happens if I access any number or String member of the class, but not for static methods: I can access them from the instance without problems.

I am running under:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.2
- Pyjnius 1.1.1
- Java 1.8.0_161

Does anyone have the same behaviour or can you suggest any solution?

Comment: Any updates on this @Alessandro? Have you figured out the problem?

Comment: Hallo @shahensha, unfortunately not, I am still stuck on the problem.

Comment: I had a similar bug and the issue was installation and path variables. It rendered some features of pyjnius useless by leading to such a crash whereas some other features were working. Very unintuitive.

Comment: That's interesting, because I had the same problem at work and at home, different machines with possibly different path variables... do you remember any specific variable or value that I should check?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't and I don't have that machine anymore.